# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException referenced from a method is not visible from class loader

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

I obtained an exception when generated a stub for a WS service by wsimport in /target/class/..... and run a spring boot application with devtools.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com....Service referenced from a method is not visible from class loader

I found that an issue with spring devtools class loader, **RestartClassLoader**, because of two different references to a Class (**RestartClassLoader and AppClassLoader**)

```
private static void ensureVisible(ClassLoader ld, Class<?> c) {
    Class<?> type = null;
    try {
        type = Class.forName(c.getName(), false, ld);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        if (type != c) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(c.getName() +
                    " referenced from a method is not visible from class loader");
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to add a reference to a jar file in spring-devtools.properties to restart.include=/.....jar

> Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE Java 9

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since they are generated classes you have to exclude them from Spring Devtools "restart" classloader.

1. Create a `/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-devtools.properties` file
2. Add properties like `restart.exclude.*` to exclude classes from restart classloader (example, you can use `restart.exclude.mygeneratedclasses=/*[generated]*.class` to exclude all classes with `generated` word as part of package or class name)
3. Done. Now you can use devtools and have no issues with WS generated classes.

Reference:

[1] https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4529

[2] https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to include JAR (which uses classloader out of spring-devtools) into spring-devtools. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61088774/6451286

Answer (score 3):

Or simply remove a Spring Dev Tools dependency if this is won't affect your application:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```