# Spring Boot with devtools call SOAP API

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap-client, spring-boot-devtools

I am deploy an project Spring Boot, using devtools(spring-boot-devtools) and call a Soap service.
I generate the Soap class into /src/main/resources/templates/generated
and add this folder as Source Code.
Because when call this Soap service, its have a problem:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ...ClassV11PortType referenced from a method is not visible from class loader

So, I was add the spring-devtools.properties file to /src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-devtools.properties
and add this line to spring-devtools.properties file:

> restart.exclude.mygeneratedclasses=/*[packageOfGeneratedClass]*.class

Then now, I can call the SOAP service successful.
But now, my project cannot reload automatically when i modified some code.
I was try to edit some code anywhere and save but not luck, my project doesnot reload.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of excluding generated files, you can **try to include JAR** responsible for loading these classes into restart classloader (used in spring-devtools).

For dependency `com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.3.2-1`, update **/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-devtools.properties** like this:

```
restart.include.jax=/jaxws-rt.*\.jar
```

Github issue reference: [Devtools cannot be use with jaxws-ri #19379](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19379#issuecomment-566074907)